# Software/vst to convert songs to midi

Tags: music, midi

I have before come across this super large midi library called polyfonix or something like that and it had thousands of midi files for full songs in a huge variety of genres mostly old school. I doubt they have created these from scratch for every single song so am wondering if there is a software/plugin that quickly converts a full song to midi? These midi files had all the various instruments including the voice.

Preferably the software runs on Windows. Happy to look into anything that works great.

Comment: I think the likelihood of finding anything that could do more than a fairly basic grasp of the main notes is not going to be possible. I used to be in charge of a Midi Library - we produced over 4,000 songs in a period of about 3 years… all by hand using highly skilled musician/programmers.

Comment: @Tetsujin Understood, thanks. Now I believe there’s no such super tool as I’ve looked and looked.